# Why is my traffic not encrypted when using pam_radius_auth?

Tags: linux, pam, openldap, radius

I'm experimenting with Freeradius and have configured an ssh gateway to use `pam_radius_auth` to my ldap servers. In `/etc/pam_radius_auth.conf` I have:

```
10.1.1.21    ny3fa4bu7my6ku7       3
10.1.1.22    ny3fa4bu7my6ku7       3
```

The authentication works but tcpdump is showing clear-text on the wire:

```
14:12:50.846356 IP 10.14.13.19.2584 > 10.1.1.21.1812: RADIUS, Access Request (1), id: 0x03 length: 116
E...o.@.?.-...........|.....t.S...... ....
....myuser..5.H.....q2g.......
... .sshd......=............(host-176.brassy.bork.net
```

I've read that Freeradius will do PEAP and EAP-TLS but I don't see any way to configure `pam_radius_auth` to use that option. Anyone have this working over some flavor of TLS?

Comment: Radius is mostly a plain protocol except the password which is basically a XOR of the password with the MD5 of the shared secret and the client info which theoretically it can be broken (with bonus points because the shared secret is the same for all users in your case). TLS will only work if the client supports it. Depending on your access the the radius server you could use encrypted port forwarding (if radius listens only udp than you need udp -> tcp -> stunnel and the reverse), a local proxy to convert udp to tls if you radius server is already set up for it or radsec if you can.